# Blown out tyre on pushchair not sitting correctly

Tags: tire

I’m not sure if the correct terminology but I recently bought a pushchair from Facebook and the tyres were deflated slightly. My dad inflated them to the correct Psi and it looked great. Left overnight and in the morning the tyre was blown out and not aligned properly, it looked like it had been blown up too much. So I deflated it, managed to get the tyre back secured then my fiancé inflated it, once again to  the correct psi. The tyre looked perfect, once again come down this morning and the exact same thing has happened?? Help!! [image]

Comment: Exactly what pressure (in PSI) are you putting in this tube ?   On the sidewall I see "16x ... something" which suggests its a 16 inch rim.  What markings are on the other tyre?

Comment: It says 35 on the tire but I’m going to try and do it less. The markings say 16x1.75  then A-1028-08 and inflate to 240Kpa(35psi)

Comment: Are there any markings on the *rim*, or even the hub, as it's a moulded wheel but not the tyre?  The reason I ask is that there are some odd 16" standards, and similar sizes.  They're apparently for bigger rims than your tyres, but because of the [absurdities of tyre sizing](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) there's a 14" tyre standard that's only a few mm smaller than your 16" where it matters, which is the bead seat diameter.

Comment: I bet this is why it was sold in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Is it the same brand of tyre as the other side?   That looks like a failure of the bead to secure into the rim.

You can try not putting as much air in, and see how it stays on.  Also it may help to check the inside of the rim for damage.

Additionally, try and "relocate" the tyre a quarter of the way around the rim, so there are different surfaces facing each other where the rim and tyre overlap.

Flipping the tyre on the rim may also help.

I suggest you use some kind of marker to draw on the rim and tyre to show where it came off.  A "whiteout" or paint pen can help.  That will show whether the flakey point moves when you shift the tyre, or stays on the same place relative to the rim.

Given its a pushchair (presumably for a small child?) then the risk of the tyre coming off is small.  If its a wheelchair for an adult then it may require a new tyre.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this info ! I’ll give it a go

Comment: Sorry I didn’t mention but yes it’s the same tire on each side and same inner tube which looks brand new. The inner tube is the same size as the tire as well

Answer (score 3):

Did the tyre sit correctly on the rim after you inflated it? I.e. was it nice and round without any bulging which could indicate a bad seat? No “high” or “low” spots?

When you install a tyre it’s also a good idea to put only a very small amount of pressure in at first. Then check all around the tyre that the tube is not pinched between tyre and rim by pushing away the tyre sidewall from the rim and looking inside.